# How do I create a discriminate union type from a record type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a mapped|conditional type such that any type such as

```
interface Car {
    color: string
    max_speed: number
    doors: number
}

type CarPorperties = SomeMappedAndConditiomalType<Car>
```

will result in

```
type CarProperties =
    {color: string}
    |{max_speed: number}
    |{doors: number}
```

Comment: Should the resulting type have 1 of the three available properties? Or should the second and third properties be optional?

Comment: This result isn't a discriminated union, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turns out to be possible: map the property types to something like `{ __tag: k, [k]: T[k] }`, then take the union of those types. This gives a tagged union type where the `__tag` property is the discriminant.

Usage example:

```js
interface Car {
    color: string
    max_speed: number
    doors: number
}

type Test = ObjectToTaggedUnion<Car>

/*
 * Test = { __tag: 'color', color: string }
 *      | { __tag: 'max_speed', max_speed: number }
 *      | { __tag: 'doors', doors: number }
 */
```

Implementation below. The details are a bit tricky since Typescript doesn't make it easy to have an object type where the `__tag` property is named literally but the `k` property isn't.

```js
type ObjectToTaggedUnion<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends string
        ? { [kk in K | '__tag']: kk extends '__tag' ? K : T[K] }
        : never
}[keyof T];
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=12&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AFQPZoIYHNcQAmAqgHYCWGpAPGgHxQC8UA3gFBSdQDaA0lOVJQA1hBAYAZlDQBdAFxR+EAB7AIpQgGcom4ACdBuDlwD8rHsOECh-AD5QA5AH0nwPA-kirKtRu3PXdygzfgU0PhkoAF9jTgVSCAA3CD02KO5RcSlZAG42fIB6ACoOIqhiAGUAQQBxAFEoOoANKoBZAAUAGTq5UoL8wTU9CWxkaABhbD1WWKhkDAAbDD0FXQNSIy4oAFtsZSdNSCJ4gFdtuBTZwgxlzVPzy5i2UEhpCF0mWEQUdCw8AhIFCo1EmejohRKUDKaHewE+LDmi2Wq30hgANFAXG5cAoHPMlnoHNFSltOPYEbt9ocIMcoKQzhc9BisXhcZSDkdCESYlDSVByVBrrd7ozmYEcY4hXpNNy+lB8kA)

Comment: I edited to try to get it to work without tuples, but I noticed a problem with the non-tuple version, so rolled back to the more complication solution using tuples. I'll keep trying to fix the non-tuple version, though.

Comment: niiice, but who will maintain that after ;)

Comment: Fixed it, and it turns out the complicated tuple-mangling is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to split product type into sum type. I think it is not possible, you can take keys, and values separately but having pairs looks not achievable.

But we can proceed another way around. So we can start from types representing every property and join them by `&` and `|`

```
// single props types
type ColorProp = { color: string }
type MaxSpeedProp = { max_speed: number }
type DoorsProp = { doors: number }

type Car = ColorProp & MaxSpeedProp & DoorsProp // product
type CarProps = ColorProp | MaxSpeedProp | DoorsProp // sum

// we can build Car directly as it would be orginal interface
const car: Car = {
  color: 'color',
  max_speed: 1,
  doors: 2
}

// or create it by merging props types instances
const doors: DoorsProp = { doors: 2 };
const max_speed: MaxSpeedProp = { max_speed: 2 };
const color: ColorProp = { color: 'red' };

const car2: Car = {
  ...doors,
  ...color,
  ...max_speed
}
```

In that way you can compose smaller types - props types into bigger composites - sums and products.

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was looking for but maybe a good enough workaround. thx